# Life is Strange art style

Tags: non-photorealistic

So, I've been obsessing over the video game Life Is Strange for the past few weeks (rightfully so, its a wonderful game) and I've been putting together a list of what makes it compelling to play. I got to the art style, as it obviously isn't realistic but not too unrealistic. I was trying to put it together myself but when I google search life is strange art style, all that shows up is fan art that doesn't well reflect it. I want to know what style of texture painting they used to give it that semi-realistic feel. How can I replicate it on my own in photoshop for my own game?

Sorry if I misplaced this question in this community, I just didn't feel right posting in graphic design.

Comment: What your asking for seems more like a tutorial in game art in the style of Life is Strange, there are many components to the art style in that game from how the meshes, textures, models, shaders, and art and gameplay programming interact, that's off-topic as a whole, if you have specific elements of the game that you have a clear outcome for, please ask those questions individually in an on-topic manner, see [help] for more information on writing questions that inspire good answers.

Comment: I don't need a tutorial, I just have to know what this art style is.

Comment: As in, what is it called?

Comment: I doubt there is a simple name I could say that would encapsulate the complex art style of the overall graphics in the game; however you may want to look into some of the posts from [Sébastien Lagarde](https://seblagarde.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/dontnod-physically-based-rendering-chart-for-unreal-engine-4/), I believe he was working at DONTNOD while they were working on Life is Strange, some of his posts might help you get a feel for what went into their art and graphics engine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about producing art in a particular style, not about game development specifically.

Comment: @JoshPetrie Don't worry, I'll mark the answer below as correct so you won't have to worry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

why not look up the artists themselves and see their work and bio's, how they approach work, etc? You may find much more this way, as opposed to googling Life is strange art style. plus if there is gdc videos or related life is strange talks, you can get a hint. The last thing is, go on their website and maybe just ask. they might have a forum.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tip. I'm a bit flustered that some salty kid went on and downvoted my question and your answer for no obvious reason. Your answer is valid and I'll see if it works.

Comment: haha it's okay. I was confused too. :) hope you find the answer.